# I am facing an error in SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am facing an error on the SharePoint Online site where I am getting an error message when opening a site. The sites are working fine but IDK why the error is popping up. I have attached the screenshot of the error [image: error message].

Comment: Are you using any custom solution developed using SPFx on this site/page? I think `alert()` is used in custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per the attached images, there is Client Query Exception with a custom expression as below:

```
Internal Project column name eq specific value
```

That guarantees that a customized client-side SPFX web part is used and raises an alert message with a log error.

Unfortunately, until you delete "`Alert()`" from your code, this behavior will persist, and the popup message will appear each time you reload the page that contains this web part.

In this scenario, you have to redeploy your SPFX solution after editing and removing the "`Alert()`" message and use "`console.log()`" to log your message in the console **just** during development rather than displaying it in the "Alert popup Message."

**See Also**

- [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)
- [Debug SPFX solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode)